# Exaggerating the pronunciation of a vowel or consonant

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, writing

Is there a word for exaggerating the pronunciation of a vowel or consonant by holding it longer than normal? When conveying this in writing, does it fall in the same category as an accent or dialect (even though it's neither) or are there other rules I should be aware of?

Examples:

- Heeere's Johnny
- lllet's get ready to rumbllle
- Halloooooooooooooooooo!

Comment: Word elongation or lengthening!

Comment: "Exaggerating the pronunciation of a speech segment" is about as close as you can get. There are so many ways to do it, and so many contexts where it happens, that it's hard -- and ultimately pointless -- to specify further.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - That's perfect, thank you!